# Android touch events with multiple views(such as a ListView in a Viewflliper)

Tags: android, view

Android touch events with multiple views(such as a ListView in a Viewflipper)

When i put a ListView inside the FlingGallery, the FlingGallery can't work when i Fling my finger.

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension of ViewFlipper and for all of its children set custom touch listener, like that:

```
public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    child.setOnTouchListener(new DragableViewTouchListener());
}

/**
 * To organize horizontal paging every child should use this implementation of OnTouchListener.
 */
private class DragableViewTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    private static final int DISTANCE_WHEN_DO_SCROLL = 5;

    private float historyDistanceX = 0;
    private float historyDistanceY = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && event.getHistorySize() > 0) {
            historyDistanceX = event.getHistoricalX(event.getHistorySize() - 1) - event.getX();
            historyDistanceY = event.getHistoricalY(event.getHistorySize() - 1) - event.getY();
        }

        boolean actionUp = (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) || (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        if (actionUp) {
            boolean horizontalStrongerThanVertical = Math.abs(historyDistanceX) > Math.abs(historyDistanceY);
            if (Math.abs(historyDistanceX) > DISTANCE_WHEN_DO_SCROLL && horizontalStrongerThanVertical) {
                onHorizontalScroll(historyDistanceX);
                historyDistanceX = 0;
                historyDistanceY = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void onHorizontalScroll(float distanceX) {
        if (distanceX > 0) {
            showNext();
        }
        else {
            showPrevious();
        }
    }
};
```

The main idea is to separate horizontal motion events (dispatch them to ViewFlipper) and vertical motion events (dispatch them to child (to ListView))