# adding more than one imageview to flipper and loading images from url to those imageviews

Tags: android, imageview, swipe

i am new to android and was trying to implement swipe effects on images loaded from url in an imageview...and i succeeded but now i want more than one url should be loaded and i can able to see them all one by one by swiping finger on the device screen as a single image covering the whole screen...
i tried very much bt fails to implement..
i dont know more than one image view will be used....some for loop & array or what!!!
just helpless b'coz attempted more than 30 times...

pls somebody help....thanx in advance......

this is my code:

```
package com.conn;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class swipe_touch extends Activity {
    private static final String LOGID = "CHECKTHISOUT";

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    private Animation slideLeftIn;
    private Animation slideLeftOut;
    private Animation slideRightIn;
    private Animation slideRightOut;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    String message = "Initial Message"; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);
      //Set up viewflipper
        viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);  

        ImageView[] img = new ImageView[i];
        j_comm_func funs = new j_comm_func();//already made this class
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = funs.LoadImage("http://65.175.77.34/newsnow/2462011/largest3/2462011-md-hr-1.jpg", bmOptions);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);


        viewFlipper.addView(img);



        //set up animations
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right);


        //put up a brownie as a starter
        setContentView(viewFlipper);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    }

    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Log.v(LOGID,"right to left swipe detected");
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                    setContentView(viewFlipper);

                } // left to right swipe 
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Log.v(LOGID,"left to right swipe detected");                    
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    setContentView(viewFlipper);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    // This doesn't work
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
            Log.v(LOGID,"screen touched");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... your method onTouchEvent doesnt work because all touch events are consumed by ViewFlipper (from docs to this activity's method:

> Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.
>   )

To implement the thing you want take a look here: [Android touch events with multiple views(such as a ListView in a Viewflliper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596909/android-touch-events-with-multiple-viewssuch-as-a-listview-in-a-viewflliper)

In your case you should do something like this:

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new DragableViewTouchListener());
```

To add zoom features you can do many things...I advise you to do the following:

1. Create the extension of ImageView: ZoomableImageVIew
2. Override the method dispatchTouchEvent like this:

   ```
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   if(needZoom(event)) {
      doZoom();
      // the event was handled. Do not propagate it to prevent handling it in ViewFlipper.
      return true;
   } else {
      // propagate the event (to ViewFlipper)
      super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
   }
   ```

   }

Good luck !!